# Best way to catch Doctrine Exceptions in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

What do you think is the best way to catch all doctrine 1.2 ORM exceptions in codeigniter framework, i would not like to wrap the entire index.php with a try catch, but neither to do a try catch before and after every query,

Comment: If not those two, which other options come to your mind? Have you tried already any of these? What's so bad with `index.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, you'll have to wrap around only single line in `index.php`. And actually, this might be good in case you have  exceptions you don't want to show (e.g. in production environment).

The second point here is that your database-related code should be concentrated in models. So you might introduce helper class, which is something like

```
class SafeQueryHelper{
    public static function safeQueryRun(Doctrine_Query $q, array $parameters, $hydration=Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_RECORD){
        try{
            return $q->execute($parameters, $hydration);
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            //Handle yur exceptions here
        }
    }
}
```

Than you'll just replace `$query->execute($params,$hydration)` in all your models to `SafeQueryHelper::safeQueryRun($query,$params,$hydration)`. Don't forget to load it with `$this->load->helper('SafeQueryHelper')` or through [the config](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html).

For record methods like `update` and `delete` - you'll have to wrap it in `try .. catch`.

Well, and if you don't have your database-related logic concentrated in models... That changes nothing, actually, but that means that you have poorly-designed application that violates the essential priinciple of `MVC` pattern, so start refactoring.

The last possible solution - is to hack into Doctrine core classes (specifically into `Doctrine_Connection`) and wrap into `try ... catch` lines that perfrom actual quering. But that's a bad idea, I really wouldn't do that.

A little update: as all Doctrine entity objects are subclaeses of `Doctine_Record` youmay extend `SafeQueryHelper` with methods for wrapping `save`, `delete` etc:

```
public static function SafeSave(Doctrine_Record $entity){
    try{
        $entity->save();
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        //catch it
    }
}
```

Than replace `$entity->save()` with `SafeQueryHelper::SafeSave($entity)`